# Trying to calculate the difference between two dates

Tags: excel, sharepoint, datediff

I'm trying to calculate the duration between when an item is created and the last time it was modified. I'm not sure what's wrong with my formula though because the equation is saying there are 41XXX days when it should be 3. This doesn't happen for all items though, only certain ones.

```
=IF(DATEDIF(Created,Modified,"d")>1,DATEDIF(Created,Modified,"d")&" days ",DATEDIF(Created,Modified,"d")&" day ")&TEXT(Modified-Created,"hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint seems confused as it is displaying the numerical (integer) representation of 8/18/2013 (US) which is 41504. Your formula displays a result directly in Excel, although the days difference is 2, not the 3 that it displays.

You might simplify it with:

```
=TEXT(Modified-Created,"d ""day(s)"" hh:mm:ss")
```

which in Excel displays

```
2 day(s) 17:34:00
```

I am not able to test it from SharePoint though.

I suppose if you really want to display either day or days then you might try:

```
=TEXT(Modified-Created,"d ""day"""&IF(VALUE(TEXT(Modified-Created,"d"))>1,"""s""","")&" hh:mm:ss")
```

This could possibly be simplified (if SP can cope) to:

```
=TEXT(Modified-Created,"d ""day"""&IF(Modified-Created>1,"""s""","")&" hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I'll give those a shot. Thank you.

Comment: It turns out that the Column in excel was set to display as text, that's why it gave the numerical value. Once I changed the column it provided the date normally. But it says 3 days not two. Is that wrong?

Comment: Note that "d" format as used in TEXT function is only good for up to 31 days (because it actually shows day of month not elapsed days) so for 32 days+ you might want to go back to something closer to your original

Comment: DATEDIF ignores the times so you won't get an accurate answer using that, try Andy's suggestion or if you need to go higher than 31 days use `=INT(Modified-Created)` to get the number of whole days elapsed

Comment: If you use `=TEXT(Modified-Created,"d ""day(s)"" hh:mm:ss")` then the **d** for number of days doesn't go beyond 31, so for longer periods you might want `=INT(Modified-Created)&" day(s) "&TEXT(Modified-Created,"h:mm:ss")`

Comment: @barryhoudini Thank you. You could put that as an answer. Batman: Yes, it should be 2 days not 3.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for letting me know, I'll make the necessary changes. It would be horrible if the time wasn't accurate

Comment: I tried all the equations in the answer but they all end up giving me 30 days

Comment: 30 days? Is that a typo - do you mean 3? That's possible if you have 1904 date system set - try using my suggestion from the comment above, i.e. `=INT(Modified-Created)&" day(s) "&TEXT(Modified-Created,"h:mm:ss")`

Comment: Okay, I tried what you said from the comments. It seems to be working. Thank you.